# Upsert on SQL Server table from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm attempting to create a small console app in C# to perform inserts on a table of Products (ITEMS) in SQL Server 2008 according to the contents of an XML file in the FASTEST way possible.  I already have an .XSD file that contains the proper mappings to the SQL table (which may not be necessary with the approach outlined below).

Here's a high-level of my approach:

1. Read the XML, using it to create a table.
2. Perform a MERGE against the ITEMS table using the table created from the XML file.
   2a. If the item exists, update it.
   2b. If the item does not exist, insert it.
3. Create a log of only the records inserted in XML.

Consider the following ITEMS table and XML file:

**ITEMS**

```
  Item_Id    Name    Price  
     1       Coke     5.00  
     2       Pepsi    3.00  
     3       Sprite   2.00
```

**ITEMS.XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <Item>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Name>Mountain Dew</Name>
    <Price>4.50</Price>
   </Item>
   <Item>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Sprite Zero</Name>
    <Price>1.75</Price>
   </Item>
```

After the import, the ITEMS table should look like:

**ITEMS**

```
  Item_Id    Name         Price  
     1       Coke          5.00  
     2       Pepsi         3.00  
     3       Sprite Zero   1.75  
     5       Mountain Dew  4.50
```

Once that's done, I also need to generate an XML formatted log file that contains the "new" record that was inserted into the table (ITEMS_LOG.XML):

**ITEMS_LOG.XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <Item>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Name>Mountain Dew</Name>
    <Price>4.50</Price>
   </Item>
```

I have tried implementing this using SQLXMLBulkLoad, but unfortunately it does not provide the logging that I need, nor does it permit me to access any of the messages returned from SQL Server (i.e. what's been inserted/updated).  Although I have an intermediate level of SQL expertise, I am fairly new to working with XML, especially in this context.  Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where are you stuck? can you send some of your code.

Comment: Are you sure that in 2 different `items.xml` files, if a product is a duplicate (by name / price) of 1 already in the database, it will have the same ID?

Comment: @ChrisW  No, they will not necessarily have the same id.  It would be possible to have the same item with two different id's.

Comment: @Sam1 Right now, I'm stuck on how to actually get the data into SQL Server.  I don't know if I should populate a dataset in C# using the XML, or just attempt to use my C# app as a wrapper for TSQL commands that actually perform the import.  In this instance, speed is very important.

Comment: @TelJanini: I would create a store proc with parameters mentioned above and pass the values in code. let me know if you need help with coding/store proc, I have an examples..

Comment: @Sam1 Any examples you could provide would be very helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: What is the typical size of `items.xml`? A few KB, several MB, GB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `merge` with `output` to a table variable and then query the table variable to build the log XML.

Put it in a stored procedure where you have the item XML as an in parameter and the log XML as an out parameter.

```
create procedure AddItemXML
  @ItemsXML xml,
  @ItemsLogXML xml out
as

declare @Changes table
(
  Item_Id int,
  Name nvarchar(20),
  Price money,
  Action nvarchar(10)
);

merge Items as T
using
  (
    select T.N.value('Id[1]', 'int') as Item_Id,
           T.N.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Name,
           T.N.value('Price[1]', 'money') as Price
    from @ItemsXML.nodes('/Item') T(N)
  ) as S
on T.Item_Id = S.Item_Id
when matched then
  update set Name = S.Name, Price = S.Price
when not matched then
  insert (Item_Id, Name, Price) values (S.Item_Id, S.Name, S.Price)
output inserted.Item_Id,
       inserted.Name,
       inserted.Price,
       $action 
  into @Changes;

set @ItemsLogXML = 
  (
    select Item_Id as ID,
           Name,
           Price
    from @Changes
    where Action = 'INSERT'
    for xml path('Item'), type
  );
```

Working sample on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68762/merge-xml)

Comment: @GR7 you might also find this one somewhat helpfull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773242/sql-process-xml-performance-insert-into-columns-in-a-table/16773592#16773592

Comment: Thanks again @Mikael! While this worked for me, when I tried it with the amount of XML data that I will receive in the app, it took 7 minutes..which is not really acceptable for me. I'm looking into SqlBulkCopy'ing the XML into a temp table and applying a MERGE from there. got any suggestions?

Comment: @GR7 never used SqlBulkCopy.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you, What I did was to create a stored procedure as below. Basically the stored procedure takes xml values and checks the flags which are passed from code and determines if it is insert or update:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = @xmlCredentials

SELECT
      item.value('@Id', 'int') As ID,
      item.value('@AgentID', 'int') As AgentID,
      item.value('@Username', 'varchar (50)') As Username,
      item.value('@Password', 'varchar (50)') As [Password],
      item.value('@IsDirty', 'bit') As IsDirty,
      item.value('@IsDeleted', 'bit') As IsDeleted
INTO #tmp
FROM @xml.nodes('Credentials/Credential') x(item)

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
      INSERT INTO Credentials (AgentID, Username, [Password])
          SELECT
              AgentID, Username, [Password]
          FROM
              #tmp
          WHERE
              ID = 0 AND IsDirty = 1
      UPDATE c
      SET c.[AgentID] = t.AgentID,
          c.[Username] = t.Username,
          c.[Password] = t.[Password]
      FROM
          [dbo].[Credentials] c
      JOIN 
          #tmp t ON t.Id = c.ID
      WHERE
          t.IsDirty = 1 AND t.IsDeleted = 0

      DELETE FROM [dbo].[Credentials]
      FROM [dbo].[Credentials] c
      JOIN #tmp t ON t.Id = c.ID
      WHERE 
          t.IsDirty = 1 AND t.IsDeleted = 1

      COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN

      DECLARE @errorMSG varchar(4000)
      DECLARE @errorSeverity int
      DECLARE @errorState int

      SET @errorMSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()
      SET @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
      SET @errorState = ERROR_STATE()

      RAISERROR (@errorMSG,
                        @errorSeverity, @errorState);

END CATCH

SELECT [ID], [AgentID], [Username], [Password]
FROM [dbo].[Credentials]
```

In code behind I have my xml and pass the xml as parameter to the stored procedure:

```
// read xml and assign it to string variable
string xml = readxml();

try
{
    string command = "EXEC SaveCredentails '" + xml + "'";
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a staging table to import the xml into a SQL Server table. Add an extra column to indicate the action (insert or update). Then use regular sql to perform upserts as usual. You can then use the staging table to generate the XML logging you need (reading the action column to determine if it was an insert or update).