# SQL calling SSIS package in stored procedure char limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a stored procedure that has an XML variable as input parameter.
Each node of the XML variable matches with a SQL column of a certain database table.
The stored procedure simply iterates over the XML nodes and inserts them into the table.

I have been using the "OPENXML" functionality in my stored procedure to do this, but I am having performance issues (query takes up to 40 sec) => [SQL process XML performance: Insert into columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773242/sql-process-xml-performance-insert-into-columns-in-a-table).
I want to boost the performance but I'm not sure where to begin. The standard XML function doesn't seem to improve, so I am looking into an alternative.

I have tried to do this functionality using SSIS packages. So from my stored procedure, I call an SSIS package that has a string variable as input parameter.
I pass the XML I receive from the stored procedure into the package as a string.
But I have come accross an issue with the xp_cmdshell functionality.
It only allows a command of max 8000 character.
This is how the code looks like:

```
--Execution SSIS Package
DECLARE @Command varchar(8000)
, @PackageLocation varchar(1000)
, @PackageName varchar(1000)

SET @PackageLocation = 'C:\SSIS\Package.dtsx'
SET @Command = 'dtexec /f "' + @PackageLocation + '" /set \package.Variables[Xmldata].Value;"' + @datastring + '"'

EXEC @ExitCode = xp_cmdshell @Command
```

The problem is that the @datastring variable can be longer than 8000 characters, so then the command fails.
Any idea how I can solve this?
Or perhaps other alternatives to accomplish this functionality?

Thanks.

Best regards,

Comment: Use `varchar(max)` for up to 2 billion characters of text

Comment: Hi, the problem is that xp_commandshell does not support the "max" datatype. If I use varchar(max), it throws an error.

Comment: Instead of passing XML, pass path to XML file.

Comment: The file isn't stored on the SQL server, so there is no way to retrieve it that way. However, I can store the xml I receive in a new "buffer" table. Then I can let the SSIS package first retrieve that data from the table and process it from there. Thanks for the tips anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I will store the XML I receive in the stored procedure in a temporarily "buffer" table, so I can retrieve it in the SSIS package and process it further.